# Set theory identity, can't derive it

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I see the following step in a textbook, and I can't follow it,

$A\cup(B\cup(C-D)-E)$
$=$
$(A\cup(B-E))\cup(C-(D\cup E)$

My progress from the LHS get stuck like this,

$$A\cup(B\cup(C-D)-E)$$
$$A\cup(B\cup(C\cap\bar{D})-E)$$
$$A\cup(B\cup(C\cap\bar{D})\cap\bar{E})$$
$$A\cup(B\cup(C\cap(\bar{D}\cap\bar{E})))$$
$$A\cup(B\cup(C-(D\cup E)))$$

But no matter how I manipulate that last forumula, I can't get to the final result. Can anyone help?

Comment: The problem may arise from an order-of-operations issue in you original expression. You seem to assume that the minus sign $-E$ is applying only to $(C-D)$ and not to $A\cup(C-D)$. So your parentheses are off in your calculation because of this issue.

Comment: Got it. Is there a bodmas for set theory operations?

Comment: Perhaps some people follow such a rule, but I don't know it. I find the original expression to be ambiguous with specifying the order of operations. But I would find it reasonable to think that $\cup$ has higher precedence than $-$.

Comment: There is a similar issue with the order of operations between $\cup$ and $\cap$ in your third displayed line.

Answer (score 2):

The right hand side is unambiguous

$$R=(A\cup(B-E))\cup(C-(D\cup E))$$ but, as noted, the lefthand side might be

$$L_1=A\cup((B\cup(C-D))-E)$$
or $$L_2=A\cup(B\cup((C-D)-E))$$

Let me give a few proofs which are not as different as they appear and then discuss the sort of proof you probably hope for.

It is possible to have a [Venn diagram for five sets](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/39/Venn5.svg/225px-Venn5.svg.png) so one might label the shapes as $A,\cdots,E$ and then shade to show the set described by each expression and compare. That is practical for three sets, not so much for five. Also Venn diagram proofs don't get a lot of respect.

For an element $u$ in the Universal Set there are $32$ possibilities for $u \in S$ or $u\notin S$ as $S$ ranges over $A,B,C,D,E.$ One could in run through all $32$ cases and if two expressions agree in all cases then they represent the same set. Once case of disagreement proves that two expressions do not describe the same set. Suppose $x\notin A,x \in B,x \in C,x \in D,x \in E.$ One can verify that $x \notin L_1$ and $x \notin R$ but $x \in L_2.$ That proves $L_2 \neq R$ but leaves it possible that $L_1 = R$ with $31$ cases yet to check. Of course one might hope to combine cases and eliminate others. The form of the expressions shows that each of  $R,L_1,L_2$  contains all of $A$ which automatically deals with half of the $32$ cases.

Consider the sets below where the membership of $n=a_0+2a_1+4a_2+8a_3+16a_4$ in $A$ depends on if $a_0=1$, in $B$ depends on $a_1$, etc. 
$$A=\{{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31\}}$$
$$B=\{{2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11, 14, 15, 18, 19, 22, 23, 26, 27, 30, 31\}}$$
$$C=\{{4, 5, 6, 7, 12, 13, 14, 15, 20, 21, 22, 23, 28, 29, 30, 31\}}$$
$$D=\{{8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31\}}$$
$$E=\{{16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31\}}$$

For these particular sets,

$$L_1=R=\{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31\}}$$ while 
$$L_2=\{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 25, 26, 27, 29, 30, 31\}}$$

I emphasize to my Discrete Mathematics students that using particular sets in this way definitively proves that $L_2 \neq R$ but does not serve as a proof that $L_1=R.$ I don't usually tell them (and when I do, they don't appreciate it) that these particular five sets are universal in the following sense. Suppose we have two expressions $F,G$ built from the variables $A,B,C,D,E$ along with the usual operators: union, intersection, symmetric difference, minus, complement and the Universal Set $\mathbf{U}$. Then $F=G$ precisely if that is true using the particular five sets above and Universal Set 
$\mathbf{U}=\{{0,1,2,\cdots , 31\}}.$

Really the three proofs sketched above are the same. The element $x=30$ which is in four of the five sets but not $A$ is of the type described above which witnessed $L_2 \neq R.$ In fact the $32$ elements of $\mathbf{U}$ are one of each possible type. If put in the appropriate place in the Venn diagram, there would be one element in each region. A Venn diagram proof for five sets involves shading in some of the $32$ regions and then comparing. Essentially that is just considering the $32$ cases. I do think that these special universal sets, which essentially test all $32$ cases at the same time, are the easiest version to apply.

But it seems that you want a proof of $F=G$ based not on elements but derived using equational axioms and definitions such as $S \cup \overline{S}=\mathbf{U},$ the two distributive laws,  $S-T=S \cap \overline{T}$ and $\overline{\overline{S}}=S$, among others, to turn $F$ into $G$ or turn both $F$ and $G$ into a common expression $H.$ (In this latter case you can reverse some of the steps to "clean up" the proof into a transformation of $F$ into $G$ which hides your process.) Of course a derivation using only a few steps is to be preferred although it may take some ingenuity to find. One can proceed fairly mechanically to convert any expression using $A,B,C,D,E$ into its full disjunctive normal form which is the union of some (or none or all) of the possible intersections such as $\overline{A} \cap B \cap C \cap  D \cap E.$ Then $F=G$ exactly if their full disjunctive normal forms are the same. This particular strategy is really the same as the other proofs above. There are $32$ possible intersections. For the special universal sets above,  $\overline{A} \cap B \cap C \cap  D \cap E=\{{30\}}=\{{x\}},$ our witness that $L_2 \neq R.$

So either be certain of your conventions for order of operations or (as above) use enough parenthesis to make the formulas unambiguous. Then manipulate one or both attempting to get to a common form. If in doubt, test with the appropriate specific universal sets such as given above.